# Flutter: How to add a widget on the left, and another one in the centre of a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-ui

I want to align a Text widget to the centre of a row, and I also want a Button widget on the left, on the same row. The text widget is surrounded with an expanded widget so that it takes up the rest of the space left by the button.

Below is what I currently have:

[image]

Red line represents the middle of the screen, the Text widget should be directly above it.
Below is my code :

```
final double _buttonTextSize = 20.0;
  final double _buttonWidth = 90.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: _backButton(),),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Encryption',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    color: MyThemeColors.textTitle(),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 5),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Button _backButton() {
    return Button(
      style: MyButtonStyles.defaultStyle(),
      child: Container(
        width: _buttonWidth,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 4.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
              child: Icon(FluentIcons.back, size: 22.0),
            ),
            Text(
              'Back',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: MyThemeColors.textTitle(),
                fontSize: _buttonTextSize,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I have 2 options for you:

1. Using Stack to put the button above the text. No calculating required :D
2. Using LayoutBuilder to calculate correctly the size of button and padding it.

   Contrait.maxWith give you the size of your space, you can using screensize(or another LayoutBuilder  widget outside to have parent size).

For me the best option is option (1).
Here is some test code(Sorry your code you provide has some custom Widgets(Button,MyButtonStyles...) and can't be copy/paste for run, so I need to create new one).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        children: const [
          OnlyText(),
          Divider(),
          OptionOne(),
          Divider(),
          OptionTwo(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnlyText extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnlyText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Material(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: Center(child: Text("this one is in middle")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const OptionTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        child: Row(children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 100,
            child: const Center(child: Text('back button')),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constrait) {
              final padding =
                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - constrait.maxWidth);
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: padding),
                child: const Center(child: Text('center screen')),
              );
            }),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const OptionOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: Stack(
            // <---- Here you go, a stack will help you
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: const Center(child: Text('back button')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const Center(child: Text('center screen')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is result:
[image]

Comment: I went ahead and went with the Stack option, thank you very much. I think you named your classes wrong though wasn't method 2 the stack method yet it is called 'OptionOne ' in the code?

Comment: ya that was my wrong naming , I edited to sync the explanation and code.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack suggestion is fine unless the text you're displaying at the center is long enough to overlap.
Here's how I did it with a LayoutBuilder:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

```
    Row(
      children: [
        const BackButton(),
        Expanded(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              const String string = 'Short title';
              final TextSpan span = TextSpan(
                text: string,
                // Note: use the TextStyle that's relevant for your case. I'm replacing the title of a SliverAppBar, so I used the default TextStyle for AppBar, headline6
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              );
              final textPainter = TextPainter(
                text: span,
                // Maybe test with rtl in the future
                textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
              )..layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

              final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
              final double textWidth = textPainter.size.width;
              final double leadingWidth = screenWidth - constraints.maxWidth;
              final double remainingSpace = screenWidth / 2 - leadingWidth - textWidth / 2;

              const Text text = Text(string);
              if (remainingSpace <= 0) {
                // If the Text overflows, we can just return the text with no positioning
                return text;
              } else {
                // Otherwise, we add blank space to the left to center the text
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(width: remainingSpace),
                    text,
                  ],
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a Sizedbox with the the same size of the left widget, remove the expanded so the Text only takes the space it need and change the alignment.

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _backButton(),),
              Text(
              'Encryption',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: MyThemeColors.textTitle(),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: _buttonWidth,
              ),
          ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
   children: [
      const Text('Start Side'),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               children: const [
                   Text('Center Side'),
                ],
         ),
       ),
       const Text('Left Side'), // with this line you get spaceBetween, after commenting will appear only in start and center side 
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

```
Row(
       children: [
          const Text('Start Side'),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                   children: const [
                       Text('Center Side'),
                    ],
             ),
           ),
         /*  const Text('Left Side'), // with this line you get spaceBetween, after commenting will appear only in start and center side */
        ],
      ),
```

[image]